# Display a Div/Flash message on link click in VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

In my laravel/Vue application, I have the following component to copy a text to clipboard on link click

```
<a @click="copyURL" ref="mylink">
        <img class="social_icon" 
          src="/images/game/copy.png"
        /></a>
        <input type="text" class="copyurl_txt" 
        value="https://sample.site/" ref="text"></input>
```

And I have following in the `script`

```
<script>
export default {
methods: {
        copyURL() {
          this.$refs.text.select();
          document.execCommand('copy');
          alert('link copied');
        }
      },
};
</script>
```

Now I want to know instead of opening an alert box, how can I show the link copied message in a div.or how to show that message as a Flash message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the flash message as a property to the Vue component and determine it's truthyness for when to display the message:

```
export default {
data () {
  return {
    flash: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  copyURL() {
    this.$refs.text.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    this.flash = 'link copied';
  }
}
```

now we can add a div with `v-if="flash"` to determine when to show it:

```
<div v-if="flash" v-text="flash"></div>
```

Now your div with the `flash` value will only appear when the user has copied the link.

**Bonus**

If your goal is to hide that flash message after a specified period of time, we can setup a watcher that establishes a `setTimeout` method that will clear the message after a period of time. Something like this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      flash: '',
      flashTick: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clearTick() {
      if (this.flashTick) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.flashTick)
      }  
      this.flashTick = null
    },
    copyURL() {
      this.$refs.text.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      this.flash = 'link copied';
    }
  },
  watch: {
    flash: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue) {
        // first we must clear the old tick if it exists
      
        this.clearTick()

        this.flashTick = window.setTimeout( () => {
          this.flash = ''
        }, 3000)   
      }
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.clearTick()
  }
}
```

1. we establish a reference to the `tick` (timeout) its self so it can be cleaned up and removed.
2. we've setup a watcher on our `flash` variable.
3. we've made sure that the value we set on `flash` does not match the old value (to prevent duplication) and we make sure the new value is set (so it doesn't fire when we set `this.flash = ''`
4. we've established a timeout of 3000 ms (3 seconds) before we hide the flash message
5. we've added a hook into `beforeDestroy()` to cleanup the tick and the flash message when the component is removed (such as navigating away, or hiding the component with a conditional)